# bootstrap popover custom position issue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am using bootstrap popover. I wanted to make a custom position which places the box to the top-left of the `<a>`. I have the code int here and it sort of works. I adjusted the tooltip js code to take into effect the placement of top-left and it yields:

```
case 'top-left':
tp = {top: pos.top - actualHeight, left: pos.left - actualWidth}
break
```

The problem right now is, when the anchor is first clicked, the box shows up somewhere way up and way further right. But, when I click to close, then click again it shows up where it needs to be. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

try to put your code in

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //Your code here
},1);
```